Gantt chart applications that have a mobile app or can be accessed easily on a phone
Gantt charts can be incredibly useful due to their intuitive visuals for time allocation. HOWEVER, the biggest limitation of many gantt chart programs is that I cannot see the chart on my phone, and it is a great inconvenience to have to be at a computer to see (but not necessarily edit) the gantt chart. This limits the locations where I can do work as I would have to lug a computer around or be somewhere near one.
I have been using GitHub projects for my gantt charts, and although it is a bit clunky for general use, it works. There is supposed to be support on the GitHub mobile app in the future, but unfortunately I don't see that happening any time soon.
What are some gantt chart applications, if any, that have a mobile app? Or, what applications can be easily accessed on a phone, e.g. a mobile website specifically created for phones (not a desktop site that can be accessed on a phone but isn't meant to)?
Apps with a desktop component are highly preferred.
